# Changing mysql time

Tags: mysql, timezone, convert-tz

I have a table , in which there is a date column. This column is of type timestamp. Data in column is showing time in IST time zone . I want to convert it's data into another timezone.
Do you have any suggestions for it.
I am using Mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT_TZ (dt,from_tz,to_tz)
```

Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2006-01-01 11:00:00','+00:00','+10:00');
```